# Rails, Cocoon : Setting values in nested form from parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I have a Booking model which has many Booking_Items. The Booking has a start_date and an end_date. The Booking_Items can have different start_date and end_date values.

I have a nested form using cocoon. It works great - allows additional items, updates, deletes. I'd like to default the start_date and end_date of any new Booking_Items to those of the parent.

Is there a correct approach to set dynamic default values for nested items?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use the `:wrap_object` option ([documentation](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#wrap_object)). This will allow you do something like

```
= link_to_add_association('add booking-item', @form_obj, :booking_items,
    wrap_object: Proc.new { |bi| bi.start_date = @booking.start_date; bi })
```

Because this is prerendered on the server, this is not really "dynamic", if the user changes the start_date/end_date of the booking in the form, new booking-items will still be rendered using the original dates. If that is what you want, you will have to revert to using js and [cocoon callbacks](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#callbacks-upon-insert-and-remove-of-items).